# PHP nested foreach to get unique size of array

Tags: php, foreach

**Here is the situation:** 
There are thousand of data. But not all of that are unique. The first `foreach` loop is unique. So, I am putting the size in a `Array` . Next loop might have same size. So, I am checking the `size` of a `variable`. If the size found in the `Array` , that means its not unique otherwise the size of that variable would be in the `Array`. The problem is I'm getting common and unique (both) size in the Array.

**PHP Code:**

```
$counter = array();
foreach ($result_all as $data){
    $message =  $data['msg'];
    $size_of_message = strlen($message);

    if(contains($message,$chittagong)){
       if(empty($counter)){
           $counter[] = $size_of_message;
       }else{
           foreach($counter as $a) {
               if ($size_of_message !== $a)
                   $counter[] = $size_of_message;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 153
    [1] => 122
    [2] => 165
    [3] => 165
)
```

**The result I am expecting:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 153
    [1] => 122
    [2] => 165
)
```

Comment: please provide input

Comment: To know if a value is already in your array, use this method : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.in-array.php
No need to manually loop through like you tried to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
           foreach($counter as $a) {
               if ($size_of_message !== $a)
                   $counter[] = $size_of_message;
           }
```

You are comparing $size_of_message with every existing element, and for most of them `if` statement will return true, adding new element to counter. And you want to add it only if no element matches it.
So you need to use `in_array()` function instead of `foreach`:

```
if (!in_array($size_of_message, $counter) {
  $counter[] = $size_of_message;
}
```

In this case you also don't need to check if array is empty.

Comment: Amazing! Your solution just worked! 

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the native function `array_unique`

```
$array = [0=>153, 1=>122, 2=>165, 3=>165];
$array_unique = array_unique($array);
print_r($array_unique);
```

Comment: I found the solution! I didn't know about Array Unique, It seems this function works too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$counter = array();
foreach ($result_all as $data){
    $message =  $data['msg'];
    $size_of_message = strlen($message);
    if(contains($message,$chittagong)){
       if(empty($counter)){
           $counter[] = $size_of_message;
       }
       if(!empty($counter)){
           foreach($counter as $a) {
               if ($size_of_message !== $a)
                   $counter[] = $size_of_message;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

or use
[Array Unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)
after foreach

Comment: I found the solution! I didnt know about Array Unique, seems this function works too.

Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using array keys unicity is an idea :

```
$result = array();
foreach ($result_all as $data){
    $result[strlen($data['msg'])] = true;
}
$result = array_keys($result);
```